# HTML select box, show updated value

Tags: grails, gsp

please help me this issues
I got this select box

```
<select name="company">
  <g:each in="${grailsApplication.config.Companies['No']}" var="no" status="index">
     <option value="${no}">${no}: ${grailsApplication.config.Companies['Name'][index]}</option>
</g:each>
</select>
```

the select box has value like this
option1    01: abc
option2    02:def

Then, I used form update, when I choose option2, it saves value to db, but on select box, default value is 01:abc, how can i change it to 02:def after update.

Comment: use javascript and set the property of the option as selected

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are sending saved value in `savedValue`:

```
<select name="company">
  <g:each in="${grailsApplication.config.company}" var="company" status="index">
    <g:if test="${grailsApplication.config.company['no'][index] == savedValue}">
        <option value="${grailsApplication.config.company['no'][index]}" selected>${grailsApplication.config.company['name'][index]}</option>
    </g:if>
    <g:else>
        <option value="${grailsApplication.config.company['no'][index]}">${grailsApplication.config.company['name'][index]}</option>
    </g:else>
  </g:each>
</select>
```